# Will using a hard coded user in firebase effect my in-app purchases?

Tags: android, firebase

I want to hard-code a user into my application so that users don't need to log in. My concern is how this will effect in-app purchasing. There is only one permanent purchase, 'GO PRO', but I want each user to need to buy it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase has the ability to authenticate users anonymously. You can save info to that anonymous user until they eventually create their own account. It stays with the device.

Also, in-app purchases can be retrieved using the method `getPurchases()`, as long as it is not consumed.

You can read more about anonymous users in Firebase [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth) and about in-app billing with `getPurchases()` [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#getPurchases).

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you.